# iOS Screenshot warning

Tags: ios, warnings, screenshot

I need to take a screen shot of some charts in my app,

Im using the following code:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[[UIColor blackColor] set];
CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

but in `[self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];` I get the warning `Instance method -renderInContext: not found (return type defaults to id)`

So, what Im I missing? to avoid this warning and successfully take my screen shot??

thanks a lot!

Comment: As well as WrightCS' answer below, you might want to look into UIContextBeginImageContextWithOptions as per http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#qa/qa1703/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010193 - what you have at present will always render at non-Retina quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to **`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`**

Comment: And add the QuartzCore framework to the project, I'd imagine.